# Inserting ENTITY declarations in DOCTYPE XSLT 2.0 Saxon9he

Tags: xml, entity, xslt-2.0, doctype

I am tasked with breaking up an XML document into individual work packages. The only part I am having trouble with is inserting graphic entity declarations in the DOCTYPE like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE frntcover PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD TM Assembly REV C" "production.dtd" [
<!ENTITY IMAGE001.jpg SYSTEM "IMAGE001.jpg" NDATA jpg>
]>
```

(Never mind the extension in the entity name, that's how they do it here.) Anyway, the entities will be constructed from all the `@boardno` that are found in the main XML file which could be in a `<figure>` or a `<graphic>` i.e. `<graphic boardno="IMAGE001.jpg"/>`

I've been using `<xsl:result-document>` to write out the doctype, but I have no idea how to get the entities in there.

I tried LexEv but I get `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Failed to instantiate class com.andrewjwelch.lexev.LexEv (does it have a public zero-argument constructor?)` I contacted Andrew and he said that LexEv is no longer supported and not the tool I need, anyway, since LexEv is for preserving entities and not for writing them to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Dr. Kay suggested, you could create it by hand using DOE (disable-output-escaping).

Here's something similar to what I've used in the past. What I normally do though is create the entity declarations using Python and then pass them in as a parameter to the stylesheet.

I use an xsl:key so I don't get duplicate declarations.

Also, you could probably refactor how the notational data is determined; especially if the notation is always the same as the file extension.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<frntcover>
    <graphic boardno="IMAGE001.jpg"/>
    <figure boardno="IMAGE001.jpg"/>
    <graphic boardno="IMAGE002.jpg"/>
    <graphic boardno="IMAGE003.jpg"/>
</frntcover>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="_gd_gnbrs" match="*[@boardno]" use="@boardno"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:call-template name="generate_doctype">
      <xsl:with-param name="root" select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pubid" select="'-//USA-DOD//DTD TM Assembly REV C'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="sysid" select="'production.dtd'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="generate_doctype">
    <xsl:param name="root"/>
    <xsl:param name="pubid"/>
    <xsl:param name="sysid"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xA;<![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE ]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$root"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string($pubid)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' PUBLIC &quot;',$pubid,'&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="string($sysid)">
        <xsl:text> SYSTEM</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="string($sysid)">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' &quot;',$sysid,'&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ []]>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@boardno][count(.|key('_gd_gnbrs',@boardno)[1])=1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="ent_decs"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[]>]]>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="ent_decs">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!ENTITY ]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@boardno,' SYSTEM &quot;',@boardno)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="matches(@boardno,'\.tif','i')">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" NDATA ccitt4>]]>&#xA;</xsl:text>        
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="matches(@boardno,'\.cgm','i')">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" NDATA cgm>]]>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="matches(@boardno,'\.jpe?g','i')">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" NDATA jpg>]]>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">UNKNOWN GRAPHIC EXTENSION: "<xsl:value-of select="@boardno"/>"</xsl:message>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE frntcover PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD TM Assembly REV C" "production.dtd" [
<!ENTITY IMAGE001.jpg SYSTEM "IMAGE001.jpg" NDATA jpg>
<!ENTITY IMAGE002.jpg SYSTEM "IMAGE002.jpg" NDATA jpg>
<!ENTITY IMAGE003.jpg SYSTEM "IMAGE003.jpg" NDATA jpg>
]>
<frntcover>
   <graphic boardno="IMAGE001.jpg"/>
   <figure boardno="IMAGE001.jpg"/>
   <graphic boardno="IMAGE002.jpg"/>
   <graphic boardno="IMAGE003.jpg"/>
</frntcover>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyQ

Comment: Thanks Daniel, what a huge help.

Answer (score 2):

Saxon does have an extension `saxon:doctype` for adding a DTD to the output document: see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/instructions/doctype

But it requires Saxon-PE or higher.

The only other option is to construct it "by hand" and output it using disable-output-escaping. Or do some post-processing using a "plain text" transformation tool such as Perl or awk.

Comment: Thank you, I will let my boss know we should consider upgrading.